# REDCap automatically populate fields from earlier records

Tags: redcap

I want to populate a dropdown menu with what was inserted in that field in early records (*not forms with piping*).

Specifically, I have a field named **"Journal"**. If someone before recorded the journal *"Metabolomics"*, I want it to appear in the dropdown menu (or something similar).

If the journal is new, I would add a text field where the new journal can be added.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you properly, you want people to select from a drop-down list and if the correct option doesn't exist you want to allow them to enter it in themselves. This can be done with a Dynamic SQL query field, which only an administrator can configure, so you'll need your local admin to do this for you.

Essentially you'll have a Dynamic SQL field (which I'm calling `[journal_query]`) to look up distinct values already entered in, and a text box field (`[journal_other]`) to enter in a new value if the dynamic SQL field doesn't contain the desired option.

The `[journal_query]` SQL field has this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT value FROM redcap_data WHERE project_id = [project-id] AND field_name = 'journal_other' UNION SELECT 'Other';
```

Which displays all existing values and adds an 'Other' option in the list.

And the `[journal_other]` field has branching logic to show only if `[journal_query] = 'Other'`.

A complexity is that the data now exists in only one of two fields, so a third field could be used to combine the two, selecting the value of `[journal_other]` if the value of `[journal_query] = 'Other'`, and otherwise, selecting the value of `[journal_query]`. If you're on a recent version and have access to the `@CALCTEXT` action tag, then you would create a text entry field (this field I would call `[journal]` since it will always contain the correct value for the record), and apply this action tag:

```
@CALCTEXT(if([journal_query]='Other',[journal_other],[journal_query]))
```

Then the value of `[journal]` (rename fields as necessary) contains the respondent's selected or manually entered journal type, which you may use for piping or for reporting.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is exactly what I needed